# Google Spreadsheet array filtering

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column in google spreadsheet name `domains` which contains the array of values like `['non work', 'work', 'work', 'non work']`, is there a way to find the count within that column which equals to `work`

Below is the screenshot of what I want to achieve.
[image]
In `Work Domain Count` column values should be respectively 3, 2 and 0

Comment: please give a sample sheet or a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH(TRIM(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"[\[\]\']",""),",")),"^work$"))
```

- REPLACE the non word characters like `'`,`[` with null
- SPLIT by the comma `,`
- Check whether each of the words MATCHes only `work`
- SUM up the TRUEs of such MATCH.

Comment: Value is in single cell not in different cells